# How to execute function using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, settimeout, setinterval

I have modal window where i have function `setConfirmation` to set modal window buttons(yes,no and ok) based on logic, now when ok button `okCallback` is called i want to set yes and no button back to modal window because these are default buttons.

Now when user click ok we closed modal window but yes and no blinks for fraction of secs so for that i created another function `resetConfirmation` that i am calling from `successCallBack` but (yes and no) buttons still blinks for a sec before modal window close.

How can i execute `resetConfirmation` `function` after 1 sec that will resolve the issue i think or any other suggestion will be appreciated as well ?

main.js

```
   var setConfirmationWinButtons = function(hideYesBtn, hideNoBtn, showOkBtn) {
     $scope.hideYesBtn = hideYesBtn;
     $scope.hideNoBtn = hideNoBtn;
     $scope.showOkBtn = showOkBtn;
 };

 $scope.successMessage = function(mesg) {
     setConfirmationWinButtons(true, true, true);
     $scope.messageText = mesg;
     $scope.confirmationWin.open().center();
     $scope.okCallback = $scope.successCallBack;
 };
 $scope.successCallBack = function() {
     $scope.confirmationWin.close();
     resetCofirmationWin();
 };
 var resetCofirmationWin = function() {
     setConfirmationWinButtons(false, false, false);
 };
```

Comment: inject `$timeout` and use `$timeout(function() { resetConfirmationWin(); }, 1000)`

Comment: so in that case do i need to declare `resetConfirmationWin` function before `successCallback` function so it does not throw error reset is not define

Comment: getting this error `angular.js:11594 ReferenceError: resetConfirmationWin is not defined` even defined before `successCallback`

Comment: i got it thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

1) 
inject $timeout, then use code:

```
$timeout(function() { 
  resetConfirmationWin(); 
}, 1000);
```

2) you also can use simple timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  resetConfirmationWin(); 
}, 1000);
```

It is more perfomant, because it does not fire `$scope.$apply()`, but you can miss model update.

It is not recommended in style guides.